# Proper MVC Repository Instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I apologize if this has been answered in a previous post; I just couldn't find the answer specific to my question.

I was watching a MVC tutorial video and in one of their controllers, they kept instantiating a repository in every method that they needed it for. I'm used to this from previous ASP.NET DAL, but they made this comment:

> ... I shouldn't be instantiating the repository in every method, I
>   should be making use of MVC's Services...

I'm curious to know what this means exactly and if instantiating a repository in my controller methods where I need it will be bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I think you should instantiate your repository only once in the Controller's constructor like this:

```
public interface ISampleRepository { }
public class SampleRepository : ISampleRepository { }

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ISampleRepository myRepository;

    public HomeController()
    {
        myRepository = new SampleRepository();
    }
}
```

You don't have to instance your repository in every *Action Method*. I'm not sure but I think every time you instantiate your repository a new *Database Context* is created.

So, instantiating the same repository multiple times seems overkilling to me.